# Many Boolean expressions in SQL Case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a question concerning boolean expressions in a SQL Case block. I´m using an Oracle database.
The column´s name will be created by the Alias name which was declared at the end of each Case Block.

Is there a way to reduce this SQL Case code example?

Comment: You need to double-check the conditions in your `CASE` expressions. `CASE` expressions  perform logic short-circuiting, i.e. they stop being processed at the first condition that is met. In your case, your 2nd and 3rd conditions are subsets of the first condition, so they'd never actually be reached. In addition, your 2nd condition is a subset of the 3rd condition, so even if you swapped the conditions to perform the most selective condition first (as is the convention), your 2nd condition would never be reached!

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of the repeated predicates by calculating the *condition* once in `CTE` and reuse it in the query as follows

```
with cte as
(select
    CASE
        WHEN {complex condition No 1}
           THEN 1
        WHEN {complex condition No 2}
           THEN 2
        WHEN {complex condition No 3}
           THEN 3
    END condition_id,
 a.*
 from my_example_table a
)
select
    value_of_column_47, 
    CASE
        WHEN condition_id = 1 
           THEN 6
        WHEN condition_id = 2 
           THEN value_of_column_18
        WHEN condition_id = 3 
           THEN value_of_column_82
    END my_first_reached_value,
...
 from cte
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use write three query three condition and use union all to combine those like below:

```
SELECT
    value_of_column_55,
    value_of_column_47, 
    6 my_first_reached_value,
    44 my_second_reached_value,
    77 my_third_reached_value

FROM my_example_table
WHERE      column_a = 1 AND column_b = 2
UNION ALL

SELECT
    value_of_column_55,
    value_of_column_47, 
    value_of_column_18 my_first_reached_value,
    value_of_column_66 my_second_reached_value,
    value_of_column_89 my_third_reached_value

FROM my_example_table
WHERE      column_a = 1 AND coulmn_b = 2 AND column_c = 8

UNION ALL

SELECT
    value_of_column_55,
    value_of_column_47, 
    value_of_column_82 my_first_reached_value,
    'Some_hardcodedtext' my_second_reached_value,
    'Some_hardcodedtext_again' my_third_reached_value

FROM my_example_table
WHERE      column_a = 1 AND column_b = 2 AND (column_c = 8 or column_r = 22)
```

But I am afraid that the conditions are properly mentioned. Your second and third condition is unreachable since there is no way that the first condition is false and second or third condition is true.

First condition is true when second condition is true and first and second condition is both true when third condition is true.

Please share sample input and desired output so that we can help you to construct  proper conditions.